# Returning Null or Not Found error if data not found in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**I am new to ASP.NET and C#**

I have a Model Class

```
public class ClientInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int ClientPackageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int RemSms { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

and to access it I have a controller

```
public ClientInfo GetClient(string username)
{        
    SmsHandler ci = new SmsHandler();
    ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();

    //the below code gives the client
    var client = dbContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == username);

    if (client != null)
    {
        clientInfo = ci.GetClientInfo(client.Id);
        return clientInfo;
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

if the client is null i want to return Client Not found error... I tried `NotFound` as above but It says this is an HTTPRequest Error..

Please Help....

Comment: What is it? MVC or WebForms? If it's MVC, then your actions should return ActionResult, not specific object. If you need to return custom object, then you need to use Json

Comment: Use try catch and throw your own custom exception.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov it is MVC and it is just a method that i need to call.if it is empty it must return some error

Comment: Then why don't you just throw an appropriate exception?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I don't think that is the thing I need.

Comment: @RoyDictus Thats the problem i dont know to throw an appropriate exception

Comment: You can throw a build-in exception such as `DataException` by using `throw new DataException("Client not found");` or you can create a custom exception (takes more work but if you want to provide very specific error details to the caller, it is worth the effort), called, for instance, `ClientNotFoundException`.

Comment: _"It says this is an HTTPRequest Error"_ - that's good, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Throw `Exception` with your defined `String`. Its a simplest way but i hope its solve your problem.

```
try
{
     ClientInfo ifno = GetClient(username);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      // ex.Message : contain client not found  
}

public ClientInfo GetClient(string username)
{        
   SmsHandler ci = new SmsHandler();
   ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();

   //the below code gives the client
   var client = dbContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == username);

   if (client != null)
   {
      clientInfo = ci.GetClientInfo(client.Id);
      return clientInfo;
   }
   else
   {
       throw new Exception("Client not found !");
   }

}
```